# How to remove the router from the quasar default app template?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I want to develop an app with only one root component without all the VueRouter machinery, and I generated the project with the quasar cli.

I cleaned the source directory to start fresh with a single A.vue component.

However, the compile process generates an app.js file that requires it (by the way, I would also like to get rid of the app.scss).
How to do that ?

(I don't need SSR, but I may build to electron.)

Answer (score 2):

You always need at least one "route" for your application to work with Quasar. Doesn't mean you have to use all their special stuff - just add a "/" base route and give it "component: A".

Pretty easy.